# how to formularize 'minimal $x$ that maximizes $A(x)$' in a computable format?

Tags: optimization, game-theory, numerical-optimization

Suppose I have a loss function $A >0$ on $x$, and I want to find a minimal x (minimial in terms of $\lVert x \rVert$) that maximizes $A(x)$.

The question is how can I formularize it so that I can numerically compute the sought $x$?

One way I could think of is
$$
x^* = \text{argmax}_x E(x),
$$
$$
E(x):= A(x) - \lVert x \rVert.
$$
But this would have some issues on prioritizing $A(x)$ and $x$ because of unbalanced scale between $A(x)$ and $\lVert x \rVert$. Moreover, $A(x)>0$ always while $-\lVert x \rVert <0$, possibly making $E(x)$ fluctuate around $0$, maybe leading to bad optimization of $E$.

Another option would be
$$
E_0(x):= A(x) + 1/\lVert x \rVert.
$$
But this is probably worse than the above as the fraction is nonlinear and has a singularity.

Would $E(x)$ above be the best (and simplest) computable form? And Can there be a closed form solution for $x^*$ in terms of the gradient $\nabla_x A$?

Note*: please assume $x$ is a vector.

**Assumption.** For any local maximum points $x^*_1, x_2^*$, $A(x^*_1) = A(x^*_2)$. (For examples, sinusoidal functions.)

Comment: What is the domain of $A$? Codomain? Is it continuous? Differentiable? Twice differentiable? Convex?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The domain of $A$ is $\mathbb{R}^d$ and as stated its codomain is $\mathbb{R}^{>0}$. And $A$ can be assumed smooth.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^*$ maximize $A(x)$, then you want to find $$\min\left\{ ||x|| : A(x) \geq A(x^*) \right\}.$$
You may be able to rewrite the constraint in a way that you do not need to compute $x^*$ separately via duality, but that is mostly a theoretical result. Practically you want to find $x^*$ first.

Comment: With all due respect, I am looking for $x$ that maximizes $A$.

Comment: @julypraise - that is not quite what the first paragraph of your question said, so I have edited it

Comment: LinAlg - and I have edited your answer to fit julypraise's intended question

Comment: @Henry thank you!

Comment: @Henry My bad. Thank you for your edit.